# How can I watch Youtube Videos on repeat?

Tags: youtube

I had many times tried to watch some video on repeat. So far the solution was to watch the video on some other website that repeats the video. Is the YouTube capable of looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

[image]

Right click the video.
This works for  Flash and HTML5 videos.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write this code in the browser console window to repeat video on loop. It offers more control.

```
var vid= document.querySelector("video.video-stream.html5-main-video")
vid.ontimeupdate = function(){if(vid.currentTime===vid.seekable.end(0)){vid.play()}}
```

Comment: haven't checked this but looks like a valid option.